# How to fix error file not found when trying to link to an image on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I’m trying to change the src attribute of an image here is the code

```html
<img id="bulbOn" src = "C:\Users\tt\Desktop\WebDevWebpage\images\pic_bulbon.gif">

<button id="buttonBulbOff"> OFF </button>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#buttonBulbOff").click( function () {
            $("#bulbOn").attr("src", "C:\Users\tt\Desktop\WebDevWebpage\images\pic_bulboff.gif");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then when I click the button to change the image the console says “error file not found” when I used the absolute path link.

Comment: Whenever you are developing any website or creating any webpage, always use relative path and not the absolute one.

Comment: Alright thank you, I eventually fixed it by using relative path. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As mention by @Vikas Keskar, you need to use a relative path. Keep the gif file inside the same directory as your html file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#buttonBulbOff").click( function () {
            $("#bulbOn").attr("src", "pic_bulboff.gif");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: remember to link Jquery inside the html file or this script will not work.

If you want to do it in vanilla JavaScript, here is the code:

```
<script>
    function bulb_off() {
        document.getElementById("bulbOn").src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    }
</script>
```

If you are going to use vanilla JavaScript instead, make sure to add `onclick="bulb_off()"` to your button tag. So your button tag should look like this:

```
<button id="buttonBulbOff" onclick="bulb_off"> OFF </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash (\) is an escape character in Javascript (along with a lot of other C-like languages). This means that when Javascript encounters a backslash, it tries to escape the following character. For instance, `\n` is a newline character (rather than a backslash followed by the letter n).

this what I got in the console when I tried to console your absolute path

console result: `C:Users tDesktopWebDevWebpageimagespic_bulboff.gif`

this is because backwards in the absolute path.

This is my attempt :

```
<img id="bulbOn" src = "C:\Users\tt\Desktop\WebDevWebpage\images\pic_bulbon.gif">

<button id="buttonBulbOff"> OFF </button>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#buttonBulbOff").click( function () {
            $("#bulbOn").attr("src", "C:\\Users\\tt\\Desktop\\WebDevWebpage\\images\\pic_bulboff.gif");
        });
    });
</script>

and to solve this issue you may for each backslash you want to output, you need to give Javascript two.
```